# How to get count of distinct following GROUP BY in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Apologies, this is certainly a duplicate but I don't know the right words to google for.

I've got a table of purchasing decisions that looks like this:

```
org_id    item_id    spend
--------------------------
123        AAB         2
123        AAC         4
124        AAB        10
124        AAD         5
```

I want to find all the items that were only bought by three or fewer organisations. Then I want to order them by summed spend.

How would I do this in SQL? NB I'm using [BigQuery SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference?hl=en).

So far I've got:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  (SELECT ??(org_id) as org_count, -- How do I get the count of different org_ids? 
         item_id, 
         SUM(spend) AS total_spend
  FROM mytable 
  GROUP BY item_id) t
WHERE org_count < 4
ORDER BY total_spend DESC
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  item_id, 
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(org_id) AS org_count, 
  SUM(spend) AS total_spent
FROM mytable
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING org_count < 4
ORDER BY total_spend DESC
```

Please note, in BigQuery:

> If you use the COUNT with DISTINCT keyword, the function returns the
>   number of distinct values for the specified field. Note that the
>   returned value for DISTINCT is a **statistical approximation** and is
>   not guaranteed to be exact.
>
> To compute the exact number of distinct values, use
>   EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT. Or, for a more scalable approach, consider using
>   GROUP EACH BY on the relevant field(s) and then applying COUNT(*). The
>   GROUP EACH BY approach is more scalable but might incur a slight
>   up-front performance penalty.

See more on COUNT and DISTINCT in Syntax section of https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#aggfunctions

Comment: This is amazing. Learned a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Might be slightly different in your brand of SQL, but this is how you would do it in SQL Server:

```
Select item_id, sum(spend) as total_spent, count(distinct org_id) as num_orgs
from myTable
group by item_id
having num_orgs <= 3
order by total_spend desc
```